# Oracle MAF application can't load remote URL on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, oracle, oracle-maf

I created a new feature that should load a remote URL connection. I also whitelisted the domain, just to be sure. The problem is that when I deploy it on my iPhone, it does not load that URL. On the contrary, on the simulator, it loads the URL without any issues.

What can be the problem?

Thank you in advance,
Razvan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer I needed. Since **MAF 2.2.1**, *non-HTTPS connections seem to fail to run on iOS*. So if you disable Application Transport Security (APS) , the problem should be solved. You can do it like this in JDeveloper :
Disabling App Transport Security for MAF Applications on iOS Devices

MAF applications that you migrate to this release of MAF enable ATS by default. You can disable ATS in your MAF application as follows:

In JDeveloper, choose **Application > Application Properties > Deployment**.

In the Deployment page, double-click the iOS deployment profile.

Choose **iOS Options**.
**Select Disable Application Transport Security** and click **OK**.

Hope to be helpful for others.

Thanks,

Razvan